# GSON does not cast Json string to class

Tags: android, json, gson, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to convert JSonObject string to some specific classes.

```
MyClass mc= new Gson().fromJson(jo.toString(),MyClass.class);
```

After this step all values of mc is null.

Value of the jo.toString() :

```
{
  "__type":"MyClass:#MyProject.Model",
  "ID":1,
  "Comment":"First Record",
  "SubClassID":534,
  "Active":true,
  "Date":"\/Date(1323087840000+0200)\/"
}
```

MyClass.java has attributes ID, Comment...

Thanks Regards...

MyClass.Java:

```
public class MyClass extends ABase
{
    private String _Comment;
    public String getComment(){
        return _Comment;
    }
    public void setComment(String value){
        _Comment = value;
    }
    private Integer _ID;
    public Integer getID(){
        return _ID;
    }
    public void setID(Integer value){
        _ID = value;
    }
    private java.util.Date _Date;
    public java.util.Date getDate(){
        return _Date;
    }
    public void setDate(java.util.Date value){
        _Date = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: if we do not see the definition of your class we can not discover the issue. The gson method you are using is ok but can't help you further.

Comment: I've added MyClass.java code.  When I use Log.d("Object",jo.toString()); I can see all values. However when I use mc.getID(), it returns null

Comment: Most probably it's just a naming mismatch. Is there any specific reason why `_Comment` should be read from `Comment` and not for example from `+__comment__+` ? Create an object of you class and save it to see more. Use a naming strategy if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the JSON element names do not match the Java field names, and no explicit alternative name-mapping configuration was provided to Gson.

Possible Solutions:

1. Change the Java field names to exactly match the JSON element names.  This of course isn't always possible, e.g., when the JSON element names include characters or formats not valid for Java field names.
2. Change the JSON element names to exactly match the Java field names.  This of course isn't always possible, e.g., when the JSON is from a third party.
3. [Provide Gson with name-mappings](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support), using either the [@SerializedName](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation, or a [FieldNamingPolicy](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html).